# Best practices with CMake, `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, and the cache?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a large C++ library, with CMake targeting [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and building into a `_build/` directory. The top level `CMakeLists.txt` uses `list(APPEND as_subproject ...)` to add a number of third party projects. A simple `Makefile` at the top level makes initiating builds easier and more consistent. The `Makefile` has two targets:

- `make clean`: runs `make -C _build clean` and then deletes the `_build` directory
- `make all`: deletes `_build/CMakeCache.txt`, runs CMake to generate the Makefiles in the `_build` directory, and then runs `make -C _build all` to do the actual build.

This has worked fairly well, until an update to one of the third party projects added the following line to their CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 CACHE STRING "Default value for CXX_STANDARD property of targets")
```

This broke our build, because every Makefile generated **after** this submodule now restricts compilation to C++11. I understand the authors' intent: if the parent project doesn't set the cached value of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, then the library sets it to "11", but otherwise it's left alone. But, now we have my library components building differently based on whether they are built before or after this project, which is way too weird for comfort.

Which brings me to my question: how should I specify my `make all` behavior? Some choices, all of which give me the heebie-jeebies:

- Continue to delete `_build/CMakeCache.txt` at the beginning of every `make all`, so I'll get the same build every time. Problem: the C++ standards enforced will be different depending on the order that the `Makefile`s are generated.
- Do not delete `_build/CMakeCache.txt` at the beginning of `make all`. Problem: the first build after a clean will be different from all subsequent builds.
- Have my top level `CMakeLists.txt` set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` in the cache, which would make my builds consistent. Problem 1: I'm passing the buck to whomever uses my library. Problem 2: someday, some submodule will set some other value in the cache, starting the arms race all over again.

What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: Please, show your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, which build that *specific* submodule and other ("normal") submodules. You describe your simply `Makefile` in so many details, but forget to describe the `CMakeLists.txt` which is actually crucial. While we could have some *guesses* about the way your `CMakeLists.txt` is written (probably, it uses `add_subdirectory` for build submodules), but it is better to **know** that, not just *guess*.

Comment: Thanks; I've added what I think is the key info; happy to add more.

Comment: Adding a name of a subproject to the list explains nothing about building this subproject. Please, show the sample of your `CMakeLists.txt`. (A general rule: instead of *describing* the code, **show** it).

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is proprietary, which is why I've been selecting pieces rather than just pasting the whole thing. I don't think my question depends on the details of how I include submodules; if you need to assume I use `add_subdirectory` then that's fine by me. If that doesn't work for you, then thanks for your time and repeated prompts.

Comment: No, we don't need the code of your **real** project. What is needed a [mcve], which **demonstrates** your problem. In that example you may change variable's names, change paths, etc. Moreover, even the complete code of the example is rarely needed: it is sufficient to provide the **simplified code** which reflects main aspects of the problem. But two lines of code, as you currently provide, is definitely insufficient for understand your problem. Take our side: How could we help you, if we don't understand your problem?

Answer (score 3):

> The top level CMakeLists.txt uses list(APPEND as_subproject ...) to add a number of third party projects.

It is not really a best-practice to rely on the sources and build-system of third-party projects. Make sure those projects install themselves with CMake configuration files, then use the [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command to locate them (and restrict their version to whichever you know is compatible). Alternatively, if those projects don't support CMake, use the [`IMPORTED` targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) feature.

This may (or may not) help you circumvent the issues with the CMake C++ standard version, but it's considered idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I've found that what I describe should NOT be happening. With CMake, variables are set during the processing phase, but aren't used until the generation phase. So, there should be no order dependencies in variable setting.

The fact that there are order dependencies points to something strange in this build system, which is beyond the scope of this question.